# classification of simple discrete modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-cohomology

our professor is teaching Serre's famous (Galois cohomology) this semester,  and he left as an exercise to classify the simple discrete modules of  the completion of the integer.  the answer is the finite fields with a certain action.

I have no idea how to do this. it seems that properties of cohomological dimensions can't be used to tackle this specific fact.  can anyone help me or give me some hint?  thanks!

Comment: If $M$ is such a module and $m$ is a nonzero element of $M$, then we may consider the map $\hat {\mathbb Z }\rightarrow M $ sending $g$ to $gm$. What can you say about this map? What's its image? When are two elements $g,h$ mapped to the same element in $M$? These may be questions to start with.

Comment: thanks,  I know this must generate the whole module, but  I don't know how to use the order argument to show $M$ is exactly the finite fieldsince this isn't the case of finite group...

Comment: You should think about my second question: when are $g,h$ mapped to the same element? Then note that, being a discrete module, there is an open subgroup $H$ of $G$, such that $H$ fixes $m$.

Comment: oh yes,  so  $G=\widehat Z = \prod  Z_p$.  and the stabilizer of a nonzero element $m$ is an open subgroup $H$,  thus $A$ is a faithful module over  $G/H$.  this quotient group is of the form $\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{k_1}\mathbb{Z}*... *\mathbb{Z}/p_l ^{k_l}\mathbb{Z}$. now since the action of the quotient group on the module $A$ is faithful,  $A$ is also of such an order.  but next how can I determine the structure and the action about $A$?  I'm sorry to ask this possibly trivial question but I'm a complete beginner

Comment: The above shows that the action of $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ on $A$ factors through $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for some $n$. Therefore $A$ is essentially a module with $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ action. This is where finite fields enter the stage. Can you classify all simple $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z]$-modules?

Comment: I was told that this is a flat algebra of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$,  and from properties in commutative algebra,  its maximal ideals intersect $\mathbb{Z}$ must be a maxmal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.  from this we can obtain the simple module is exactly a finite field.   -----but what I didn't understand is the last step.  (I only know the simple modules are quotients modulo maximal ideals of the group ring.) and how can we determine the action of the group ring on this module? (write explicitly in the original form $\widehat {\mathbb{Z}}$)  ?

Comment: *the simple modules are quotients modulo maximal ideals of the group ring* Yes, and the group ring $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z]$ is nothing but the ring $\mathbb Z[T]/(T^n-1)$. Try to convince yourself that any quotient of this ring by a maximal ideal is a finite field, and that the action of $1\in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ on such a quotient is nothing but multiplication by an $n$-th root of unity of that finite field.